# Removing items from an array based on a threshold limit?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a `Java` assignment and I need to include a method that will remove from an array of Homes (a type of object created by the assignment scripts) all homes with a monthly cost above an input threshold. My code works for some cases, but some homes will be removed in some cases but not others.

```
public int remove(double cost) {
   int count = 0;
   int index;
   do {
      index = 0;
      while ((this.homeList[index].costPerMonth() < cost) 
         && (index < this.numHomes)) {
         index++;
      }
      if (index < this.numHomes) {
         for (int i = index; i <= this.numHomes - 1; i++) {
         //If the cost is higher than the threshold, that
         //home is removed and all other homes are slid up
         //one position in the list
            if (index < (this.numHomes - 1)) {
               this.homeList[i] = this.homeList[i + 1];
            }
            count = count + 1;
            this.numHomes = this.numHomes - 1;
         }
      }
   //Do while loop ends when all the homes in the list
   //have costs lower than the threshold 
   //When index == numHomes, it has cycled through the whole
   //list without stopping for a cost too high 
   } while (index != this.numHomes);
   //Return the number of homes removed 
   return count;
}
```

`homeList` is my array of homes, `costPerMonth()` is a method written in the `Home` class, and `numHomes` is an instance variable I use to keep track of how many homes are in the array at any given point.

This code has given correct answers, but a specific case keeps causing me problems: 
For a test in which I have defined a home that has a monthly cost of $1234.56 and I set the threshold to 1980, the code will not remove the one home if it's the only home in the list (good). But if I run the code after adding multiple homes to `homeList`, and I run the code with the same threshold 1980, it removes that home with the $1234.56 monthly cost.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should check that `this.homeList[index] != null` before calling `this.homeList[index].costPerMonth()`.

Comment: Get rid of the whole lot and replace with a `List`.

Comment: A bug is exist first check the size , change
 `while ((this.homeList[index].costPerMonth() < cost) 
         && (index < this.numHomes)) {
         index++;
      }`
to 
`while ((index < this.numHomes) 
         && (this.homeList[index].costPerMonth() < cost)) {
         index++;
      }`

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange written code you got there ;) Null pointer exception happens when you call a method or access a property of an object which is currently null. In your code that is probably the call to `.costPerMonth()`. You do it somewhere on a null element.

This loop:

```
 while ((this.homeList[index].costPerMonth() < cost) 
         && (index < this.numHomes)) {
         index++;
      }
```

finds the number of homes that have costPerMonth

```
 if (index < this.numHomes) {  // that will always be true seeing how index grows in the loop above
```

Why don't you just create a second array and move the items there? Something like:

```
Home[] resultArray=new Home[this.numHomes]
 int resultArrayIndex=0;
 for (int i = index; i <= this.numHomes - 1; i++) {
   if(this.homeList[index].costPerMonth() < cost)
         resultArray[resultArrayIndex++]=this.homeList[index];
```

It might cause some more memory usage but it will make you code much easier to understand. If that's for an assignment for arrays. If you can do it anyway you like you can check java collections api. For example ArrayList which is basically a dynamic size array and will make your work easier.

Comment: Thanks! I do need to somehow get the modified data into the original homeList array because that's what all my methods work on. So this should work if I create the resultArray as a placeholder and then just set homeList to resultArray?

Comment: yes in the end you can swap the values.  Or you can add some logic for moving elements around